# Is it possible to use single method to authorise multiple controller action in Rails Pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I am created new rails application and I want to restrict user actions based on **only one condition** like record can be editable by owner(created_by) and sub-owner(Added by owner). I have models like App, User and controller like AppController. In AppController I have more than one actions like index, create, show, update, delete. I have one policy like AppPolicy. Here I need to create only one method to verify all actions but by default each action requires another method like action_name? in policy class.

Example

Existing code:

```
class AppPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
     scope
   end
 end

 def action1?
  record.users.include? (user)
 end

 def action2?
  record.users.include? (user)
 end

 def action3?
   record.users.include? (user)
 end

end
```

From above code we can see a same condition reside in all methods. I need to use only one method to verify action1, action2, action3. I don't know this is possible or not in Pundit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same problem.

I can think about 2 solutions:

### solution 1

When you know all the actions that could be called.

You can use `define_method`, like this

```
[:action1?, :action2?].each do |m|
  define_method(m) { record.users.include? (user) }
end
```

### solution 2

When you don't know all the actions. (this could be dangerous)

You can use a combination of `method_missing` and `respond_to_missing`. The latter is needed since pundit will call internally `respond_to` before calling the corresponding method of the policy.
Example:

```
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    record.users.include? (user)
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    true #Here it would be better to add some conditions
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also just had this same problem.

Ive done it with an admin policy. In any controller action, do `authorize [:admin, :user], :admin?`

The first part tells Pundit what policy to use, the second which authorization method.

The policy class:

```
class Admin::UserPolicy
  attr_reader :current_user, :model

  def initialize(current_user, model)
    @current_user = current_user
  end

  def admin?
    @current_user.has_admin_privilege?('full_admin')
  end
end
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use cancan (or cancancan) gem [rubygems link](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancan)

You can create the ability configuration file with

```
rails g cancan:ability
```

The `authorize!` method in your controller will raise an exception if the user is not able to perform the given action, so call it on `before_action` callback.

Documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cancan/1.6.10)

Comment: this advise makes little to no sense and not even an answer, because OP uses Pundit.